# PIC device not detected by MPLab X 5.25 IPE

Tags: embedded, pic, mplab

i am having problem in burning my hex file to my pic18f4550. I use a PicKit 3 with MPLab X IPE v5.25. MPLab can detect the PICKit 3 since it displays the serial number. But when i try to connect with the PIC device, it shows me an error "Connection Failed". I have tried it with other computers and it works. Any ideas how will i make it work in my laptop? Every idea is appreciated.

Comment: Have you switched on the power from the MPLABx IPE?

Comment: I use an external supply since mplab strangely does not power the device even if i switch it on.

Comment: Then you had to be sure to switch off the the power in MPLABx IPE. But for me the power supply with MPLAB works fine.

Comment: If it works on other PC with the same PicKit and board than: check if you have the latest drivers (or the same like one the other PC), try other USB port or USB cable.